# Replacement Cooler For Asus 760 OEM 3GB Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-cards, cooling

I'm looking for recommendations for a replacement cooler for my ASUS OEM 3GB Graphics Card. It's a single fan, however the mounting bracket for the fan is X shaped rather than the tri-point versions I've found while searching. If I could just replace the fan that would be great, however if I have to replace the cooler I don't mind. It just needs to be under $25.